# Android: Receiving NullPointerException when initialize a Canvas object

Tags: android, image, canvas, nullpointerexception

I have NullPointerException when the code gets to the canvas initialization. When creating the canvas I passed in a blank bitmap to it.

This is my code where the nullpointerexception occurs.

```
    private static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap unscaledBitmap, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {

      Rect srcRect = calculateSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(), dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);

      Rect dstRect = calculateDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(), dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);

      Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(), Config.ARGB_8888);

      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);

      canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

      return scaledBitmap;

}
```

This is the stack trace of the code.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.PhotoEditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.graphics.Canvas.(Canvas.java:82)
>   at ImageManupulator.createScaledBitmap(ImageManupulator.java:101)
>   at utils.ImageManupulator.ImageResizing(ImageManupulator.java:27)
>   at android.PhotoEditActivity.updatePhoto(PhotoEditActivity.java:219)
>   at android.PhotoEditActivity.access$0(PhotoEditActivity.java:211)
>   at android.PhotoEditActivity$2.onItemClick(PhotoEditActivity.java:279)
>   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
>   at android.PhotoEditActivity.onCreate(PhotoEditActivity.java:128)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   ... 11 more

Comment: which line is ImageManupulator.java: 101?

Comment: `unscaledBitmap` is probably the one that's `null`.

Comment: You are declaring and drawing the Bitmap in static function. Just Pass the canvas in function parameters and draw bitmap in function.

Comment: eightx2 is right probably the unscaledBitmap. Is there a chance unscaledBitmap.getWidth() or unscaledBitmap.getHeight() return 0 or -1. Cause I think that is the one which causing the problem. If unscaledBitmap is null, getWidth and getHeight part of the code will throw an error before the line that initializing the Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever your calling this method, please check your parameters unscaledBitmap and scalingLogic are not null as these 2 only are the objects used with in your method implementation.